# Android application consuming WCF

Tags: android, wcf

I'm new in Android and I have to do an application (in android) that consumes a NET WCF service with httpbasicbinding. I have heard about use of ksoap2-android, json and restfull but I don't know which is the best way for my app.

Anyone can suggest me anything?

Another problem is my WCF service return complex objects made by Linq To Sql and I don't know how can I use it in Android.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: BasicHttpBinding exposes SOAP service.

Answer (score 1):

If you use oData web services you can use the [odata4j client library](http://code.google.com/p/odata4j/).

If you're using [Service Stack](http://www.servicestack.net) to develop your web services you can use any REST client to easily consume them (in any format i.e. JSON, XML, JSV, SOAP, etc). The [Hello World example](http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/) shows a number of different ways you can consume a single web service.

Comment: Actually I'm not using oData nor Service Stack. Y made my services with VS 2008 in .NET 3.5 framework and the persistant layer with Linq To Sql